# Having an issue aligning divs in a table-less web page design

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am trying to create a web page that has a tabular layout but without using table elements. The problem I am having is that whenever I add text to any of the divs the layout changes. I am not sure why this is happening. Attached below is the code. It is a simplified version of the layout containing only the divs and plain text. I have color coded the divs so that each stands out.

The two versions in this code are identical. The only difference is that the second one has the text added to it. Notice how the the divs shift downward when the text is added. Does any one have a solution to why this is happening?

Thanks in advance for any help that you might be able to give me.

PeteM

****CSS****

```
.content {
            margin: 0px auto;    /*center the content all browsers except IE*/
            text-align: center;  /*center the content IE*/
            width: 1212px;
     }
    body { background-color:yellow; }
    .table{ display: table; width: 1212px; }
    .row-one { display: table-row; width: 1212px; }
    .column-one { display: table-cell; width: 256px; }
    .column-two { display: table-cell; width: 956px; }
    .image-one {
            height: 256px; 
            width: 256px; 
            background-color:red;
    }
    .image-two {
            height: 256px; 
            width: 256px; 
            background-color:green;
    }
    .image-three {
            height: 256px; 
            width: 256px; 
            background-color:purple;
    }
    .image-four {
            height: 256px; 
            width: 256px; 
            background-color:tan;
    }
    .image-five {
            height: 256px; 
            width: 256px; 
            background-color:maroon;
            float:right; 
    }

    .top-middle {
            background-color:pink; 
            width: 700px; 
            height: 256px;              
    }
    .bottom-right {
            width: 956px; 
            height: 768px; 
            background-color:blue;
    }
```

***HTML****

```
<div class="content">
        <header>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </header>
        <div class="table"><!--table-->
            <div class="row-one"><!--table row 1-->
                <div class="column-one"><!--table COL 1-->

                    <div class="image-one"></div>

                    <div class="image-two"></div>

                    <div class="image-three"></div>

                    <div class="image-four"></div>

                </div><!--END table COL 1-->
                <div class="column-two"><!--table COL 2-->

                    <div class="image-five"></div>

                    <div class="top-middle">

                    Welcome to My Home on the Web!<br />    
                    <br />  
                    I am a Multimedia Computer Programmer and Web Designer and I am currently living in New York City.<br />    
                    <br />  
                    Hello to all of the visitor's to this site. It is designed to be a place to view all of my current projects.<br />  
                    <br />      
                    Below are links to games and multimedia projects that I have recently created...
                    </div>

                    <div class="bottom-right">

                        list item 1<br />
                        list item 2<br />
                        list item 3<br />
                        list item 4<br />
                        list item 5<br />

                    </div>              
                </div><!--END table COL 2-->
            </div><!-- END table row 1-->
        </div><!--END table-->
        <footer>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </footer>
    </div> <!-- END content -->
```

****HTML w/o Text***

```
<div class="content">
        <header>
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </header>
        <div class="table"><!--table-->
            <div class="row-one"><!--table row 1-->
                <div class="column-one"><!--table COL 1-->

                    <div class="image-one"></div>

                    <div class="image-two"></div>

                    <div class="image-three"></div>

                    <div class="image-four"></div>

                </div><!--END table COL 1-->
                <div class="column-two"><!--table COL 2-->

                    <div class="image-five"></div>

                    <div class="top-middle"></div>

                    <div class="bottom-right"></div>

                </div><!--END table COL 2-->
            </div><!-- END table row 1-->
        </div><!--END table-->
        <footer>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </footer>
    </div> <!-- END content -->
```

***HTML using Table elements**
Here is the same page using table elements. Notice how the divs all line up correctly even though there is text in them. Whatever this issue is it probably has to do with the display:table attribute. Writing the code this way everything looks correct except there is a border spacing between the two columns. I'm not sure what is causing that also.

```
<div class="content">
        <header>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </header>
        <table><!--table-->
            <tr><!--table row 1-->
                <td><!--table COL 1-->

                    <div class="image-one"></div>

                    <div class="image-two"></div>

                    <div class="image-three"></div>

                    <div class="image-four"></div>

                </td><!--END table COL 1-->
                <td><!--table COL 2-->

                    <div class="image-five"></div>

                    <div class="top-middle">

                    Welcome to My Home on the Web!<br />    
                    <br />  
                    I am a Multimedia Computer Programmer and Web Designer and I am currently living in New York City.<br />    
                    <br />  
                    Hello to all of the visitor's to this site. It is designed to be a place to view all of my current projects.<br />  
                    <br />      
                    Below are links to games and multimedia projects that I have recently created...
                    </div>

                    <div class="bottom-right">

                        list item 1<br />
                        list item 2<br />
                        list item 3<br />
                        list item 4<br />
                        list item 5<br />

                    </div>              
                </td><!--END table COL 2-->
            </tr><!-- END table row 1-->
        </table><!--END table-->
        <footer>
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </footer>
    </div> <!-- END content -->
```

Comment: If you are making a real table (rows and columns with data to the user to read), there's no reason to stay away from `<table>`. People just don't like tables for things that are not tables, such as the entire page. There is no "performance" or "compatibility" loss from using tables. Also, you mentioned "below is the code" but there is nothing attached.

Comment: I was asked to do this assignment without using tables. So instead I am using divs and the CSS properties, display:table, display:table-row, display:table-cell.

Comment: Most certainly provide a [JS Fiddle Please](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names). If you cannot *attach your code* we are shooting in the dark. Also, `static sizes` for elements are becoming more and more obsolete.

Comment: I wish I had the time right now to answer this, I may yet, but later.  one thing.  If you're using non-table, which I am a fan of.  You should almost never need any sort of "float" and most divs should have a display parameter.  The one you label with display will affect the immediately following div.  display:"block", "inline-block", or "inline"; are the options. Also, box-sizing:border-box; may be helpful.

Comment: So are you wanting it to be using the tables method or divs?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any attached code. However, I imagine that your issue might have something to do with [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) whenever you add the text. Just a guess based off of the description.